# Reuse table parameters

Tags: asciidoc

in my document I have 2 different kinds of tables. Each of these is formated differently.

```
[frame="none", grid = "none", stripes=none]
[frame="topbot", grid = "rows", options="header"]
```

Width und cols I want to define for each table individually.
Is there a way to define there format beforehand and just refer to this definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use an attribute to define table parameters:

```
= Document

Lorem ipsum...

:table1: frame="none", grid = "none", stripes=none
:table2: frame="topbot", grid = "rows", options="header"

[{table1}, cols="a,a"]
|===
| A
| B

| A
| B

| A
| B
|===

[{table2}, cols="a,a,a"]
|===
| A
| B
| C

| A
| B
| C

| A
| B
| C
|===
```

That should look like:
[image]